# How to pass an input from a django-plotly-dash app to other apps of the same Django template?

Tags: python, django, plotly-dash

I am using django-plotly-dash to insert a set of dash apps, each representing an individual graph, into a Django template. Each app or graph has its own input fields to select data and plot it for a given time frame.

Now, I would like to move the date-select/input field to one separate dash app, in order to select the data for all apps within the template but I struggle to find a solution.

I consulted the documentation at https://django-plotly-dash.readthedocs.io as well as the examples at https://djangoplotlydash.com/.

Any hints on how to move forward are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If the selection is per-user, then one approach is to store the selection within that user's session and share it between the dash apps. This is the principle behind the [worked example](https://django-plotly-dash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/demo_notes.html#session-example) in the documentation.

The basic idea is to register callbacks using `extended_callbacks` - this will provide extra arguments to your callbacks, including the current user's session. You can then use code along the lines of

```
@dash_app.expanded_callback(
dash.dependencies.Output("alert", 'children'),
[dash.dependencies.Input('button', 'n_clicks'),]
)
def session_callback(n_clicks, session_state=None, **kwargs):
    if session_state is None:
        raise NotImplementedError("Cannot handle a missing session state")
    csf = session_state.get('demo_state', None)
    if not csf:
         csf = dict(clicks=0)
         session_state['demo_state'] = csf
    else:
        csf['clicks'] = n_clicks
    return "Button has been clicked %s times since the page was rendered" %n_clicks
```